# Prove that $f(U\cap\partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n})\subset \partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}.$

Tags: general-topology

Let $U,V$ two open sets of $$ \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid x_n\geq 0\}$$ for the induced topology and $f:U\longrightarrow  V$ an homeomorphism. Prove that $$f(U\cap\partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n})\subset \partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}.$$

I denote $\partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}$ the boundary of $\overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}$.

**My idea:**

Let $y\in f(U\cap \partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n})$. Then there is an $x\in U\cap\partial \overline{\mathbb H}^{\ n}$ such that $y=f(x)$, i.e. 
$$f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},0)=(y_1,...,y_n)$$
where $x_1,...,x_{n-1}\in U$.

So, I have to prove that $y_n=0$, but I don't know how.

Comment: This is nontrivially difficult. Think of the proof for $n=1$; the boundary is not a cut point but the interior is. To mimick this in higher dimensions you want to know either what homotopy or homology groups are.